# How to upload cropped image

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am using `image picker` and `crop` but I am failing to upload it correctly.

this is the service I am using:

```
getMedia(): Promise<any> {
 return this.imagePicker.getPictures(this.options).then((fileUri) => {
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      return fileUri
    } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      fileUri = 'file://' + fileUri;
      /* Using cordova-plugin-crop starts here */
      return this.crop.crop(fileUri, { quality: 100 });
    }
 })
 .then((path) => {
   console.log('path in .then((path)): ', path)
   return path;
 })
}
```

the above returns path like this: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.jobsaf211675/cache/1500181851170-cropped.jpg?1500181872091`

the function for upload:

```
    async upload(): Promise<void> {

    let url = 'valid URL';
    let options = {
       fileKey: 'file',
       fileName: this.selectedImage.split('/').pop(),
       mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
       chunkedMode: false,
     };

     console.log('options from upload: ', options)   // this returns fileName: `1500181851170-cropped.jpg?1500181872091`

     this.fileTransfer.upload(this.selectedImage, this.URL, options, false).then(res => {
     if (res.responseCode === 200){
         let data = JSON.parse(res.response);

         const ProfilePicInfo = {
            name: data['result']['files']['file'][0].name,
            mime: data['result']['files']['file'][0].type,
            size: data['result']['files']['file'][0].size
         };

         console.log('ProfilePicInfo: ', ProfilePicInfo);  // the name object here changes , the field name here is --> `name: "1500181875074.jpg?1500181872091"`

         this.profilePicService.postProfilePic(url, ProfilePicInfo).subscribe(res => {
           console.log('result after posting pic: ', res)
         }, err => {
          console.log('error posting profile pic: ', err)
       });
     }
   }, err => {
      console.log('image upload failed: ', err)
   });
 }
```

so the result name saved like this: `1500181875074.jpg?1500181872091` which is not readable and I cannot download it back... what am I doing wrong here! and which name is the correct one, thanx

Comment: Can't you just split the file name again with '?'?

Comment: you mean splitting this `1500181851170-cropped.jpg?1500181872091` to be this `1500181851170-cropped.jpg` ?? and if so , how to do it!

Comment: this.selectedImage.split('/').pop().split('?')[0]